# AngularJS flash message clearing

Tags: angularjs

I've just started using [angular-flash](https://github.com/gtramontina/angular-flash/blob/master/angular-flash.js) and the messages are coming up, but where should I clear the messages?

Do I just set flash.message('') under every action or put it in the route somewhere?
Is there a way to do this on a timer so it fades out? I see in the code that there is a timeout feature but where do I initialise that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking into the source code to try and figure out what is going on, a quick and dirty fix would be to do this when you want to clear the messages:

```
flash([]);
```

Since all of your flash messages are in an array, I assume you can handle it like any array.

The reason I'm saying it's dirty is because I'm assuming there's a better way to do this,                                               with something like a clear() or empty() function.

Comment: This does clear the messages, but where would I put this line? It would be better if I could set a timeout and it would fade away after X seconds. I see a timeout in the code but cannot workout how to set that.

Answer (score 1):

I have found my answer to clearing:

```
  flash('notice', 'User details updated!')
  $location.path "/users/#{$stateParams['id']}"
  $timeout (-> flash()), 2000
```

Comment: Hay above code giving me error, can you correct it.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it with your own service:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
  .service('ff', ['$rootScope', 'flash', '$timeout', function ($rootScope, flash, $timeout) {

    var log = function(level) {

      function inner(msg, sticky) {
        if (level == 'info') flash(msg);
        else flash(level, msg);
        var promise = $timeout(function() {
          var idx = _.findIndex($rootScope.messages, ['text', msg]);
          $rootScope.messages.splice(idx, 1);
        }, 2000);
        if (sticky) {
          $timeout.cancel(promise);
        }
      }

      return inner;
    };

    return {
      info: log('info'),
      error: log('error'),
      warn: log('warning'),
      success: log('success')
    };
  }]);
```

And in the controller:

```
ff.info("This will go away.");

ff.error("This will stick", true);
```

Now it's just a pity multiple calls to `flash` doesn't just append to an array, i.e. replace [this line](https://github.com/gtramontina/angular-flash/blob/85171a89b18266374e38ea7031a192b545019892/angular-flash.js#L66) with

```
if (typeof $scope.messages !== 'undefined') {
  $scope.messages = $scope.messages.concat(messages);
} else {
  $scope.messages = messages;
}
```